# Can you change citation style to numerical for natbib in rmarkdown or bookdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible in rmarkdown or bookdown when using `citation_package: natbib` and `biblio-style: apalike` to have citations as "[1]" rather than "(Author et al. Year)"?

I think you could achieve this in LaTeX by setting:
`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`, but putting this in the preamble.tex did not change anything.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have made it work. In the preamble.tex file: `\setcitestyle{numbers,square}`